# Call function first time after specified time interval

Tags: javascript

I am using Firefox and I want to call a function (Logger) 10 seconds after the page has loaded. I am using this code

```
if (document.addEventListener)
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Logger, false)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("func_name", 10000);
};
```

Where `func_name` is normal function:

```
function func_name(){
 // code here...
}
```

Or you can even do this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
     // your code...
  }, 10000);
};
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: this is not working in firefox. Also i have another setTimeout code in my script. Will it conflict?

Comment: i cannot do that as the entire page functioning works on the other timeout..Can't we have two timeouts? I am not sure why your code is not working. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I check and found that window.onload does not work properly in firefox. The right way is to use document.addEventListener but dont know how to use with setinterval

Comment: window.onload works perfectly fine in firefox. I suspect that your setTimeout()s are overriding each other.  Also of note, the DOMContentLoaded event fires earlier than window.onload, so they aren't exactly equivalent.